# Make the array.filter filter null values as well

Tags: javascript

This is my array from a webservices.

```
array = [{category: "Amphibian", common_name: "African Clawed Frog"},{category: "Mammal", common_name: "African Pygmy Hedgehog"},{common_name: "African Spurred Tortoise"}];
```

now when I call this function like this:

```
function filterByKey(array, "common_name", "African", "includes") //it works..
```

so now when I want to filter by category, like this:

```
function filterByKey(array, "category", "Mammal", "includes") // it doesn't work
```

but because the third row doesn't have a category column, it fails stating the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

this is my function

```
function filterByKey(array, key, value, matchOrContain) {
    if (matchOrContain == "match") {
        var result = array.filter(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => o[key].toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()));
    } else if (matchOrContain == "includes") {
        var result = array.filter(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => o[key].toLowerCase().includes(value
            .toLowerCase())));

    }

    return result;
}
```

How can I avoid getting that error but in the same times filter out the array? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest tweak would be to use optional chaining, to only call `toLowerCase` if the key exists:

```js
const array = [{
  category: "Amphibian",
  common_name: "African Clawed Frog"
}, {
  category: "Mammal",
  common_name: "African Pygmy Hedgehog"
}, {
  common_name: "African Spurred Tortoise"
}];
console.log(filterByKey(array, "category", "Mammal", "includes"))

function filterByKey(array, key, value, matchOrContain) {
  if (matchOrContain == "match") {
    var result = array.filter(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => o[key]?.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()));
  } else if (matchOrContain == "includes") {
    var result = array.filter(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => o[key]?.toLowerCase().includes(value
      .toLowerCase())));

  }

  return result;
}
```

You could significantly DRY the code by declaring the callback up front, too:

```js
const array = [{
  category: "Amphibian",
  common_name: "African Clawed Frog"
}, {
  category: "Mammal",
  common_name: "African Pygmy Hedgehog"
}, {
  common_name: "African Spurred Tortoise"
}];
console.log(filterByKey(array, "category", "Mammal", "includes"))

function filterByKey(array, key, value, matchOrContain) {
  const lowerValue = value.toLowerCase();
  const test = value => (
    matchOrContain === 'match'
      ? value?.toLowerCase().includes(lowerValue)
      : value?.toLowerCase() === lowerValue
  );
  return array.filter(
    o => Object.values(o).some(test)
  );
}
```

If you can't use optional chaining, then use the more vebose method and check to see if the value is truthy before calling a method on it:

```js
const array = [{
  category: "Amphibian",
  common_name: "African Clawed Frog"
}, {
  category: "Mammal",
  common_name: "African Pygmy Hedgehog"
}, {
  common_name: "African Spurred Tortoise"
}];
console.log(filterByKey(array, "category", "Mammal", "includes"))

function filterByKey(array, key, value, matchOrContain) {
  const lowerValue = value.toLowerCase();
  const test = value => value && (
    matchOrContain === 'match'
      ? value?.toLowerCase().includes(lowerValue)
      : value?.toLowerCase() === lowerValue
  );
  return array.filter(
    o => Object.values(o).some(test)
  );
}
```

Comment: Note that the null-safe operator is pretty new, it will work in recent browser, and in older ones only when using transpilers like TypeScript or BabelJS

Answer (score 2):

On your code, on these parts,

```
array.filter(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => o[key].toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()));
array.filter(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => o[key].toLowerCase().includes(value
            .toLowerCase())));
```

You have converted `o[key]` to lowerCase even if it's not existed. So it throwed error.

You need to check the validation of `o[key]` first and when valid, do the comparison as follows.

```js
const array = [{
  category: "Amphibian",
  common_name: "African Clawed Frog"
}, {
  category: "Mammal",
  common_name: "African Pygmy Hedgehog"
}, {
  common_name: "African Spurred Tortoise"
}];


function filterByKey(array, key, value, matchOrContain) {
  if (matchOrContain == "match") {
    var result = array.filter(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => o[key] && o[key].toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()));
  } else if (matchOrContain == "includes") {
    var result = array.filter(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => o[key] && o[key].toLowerCase().includes(value
      .toLowerCase())));

  }
  return result;
}

console.log(filterByKey(array, "common_name", "African", "includes"));
console.log(filterByKey(array, "category", "Mammal", "includes"));
```